# two tables joined, select option , how to fill a value automaticly

Tags: php

hello i have two tables joined , and i'm trying to fetch some values into a select box, making it so that when a user selects one of the options , when submitting the form it will post the other values associated

```
<select name="matricula[]">
      <?php 
          // use a while loop to fetch data 
          // from the $all_categories variable 
          // and individually display as an option
          while ($matricula = mysqli_fetch_array(
                  $result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)):; 
      ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $matricula["matricula"];
    
              // The value we usually set is the primary key
          ?>">
              <?php echo $matricula["matricula"];
                  // To show the category name to the user
              ?>
          </option>
      <?php 
      
          endwhile; 
          // While loop must be terminated
      ?>
  </select>
```

in this code i need to add the value automatically and insert on form submission : "tipocomb" it has already got a table named "combustivel" created with the values and when i use json encode it displays the two arrays connected in the view source
it's just a question of how to echo the "tipocomb"?

Comment: The script that processes the form should use the value that was submitted to query the database. Don't put all the information in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something like that you need js to post form that has hidden inputs with related data. Simpler solution would be when you read the post in your controller fetch related data and do further logic there.

Comment: i tried this below the code but on view source appears array to string conversion error
``` <input readonly hidden type="text" name="tipocomb"
                value="<?php echo ['idcomb']; ?>" ></input><?php echo ['tipocomb']; ?> ```

Comment: Array to string error is when you are trying to change array to string.

['idcomb'] is an array and echo is trying to change array to string